# WifiManager enableNetwork reverts to previous network after a few seconds

Tags: android, wifimanager, android-connectivitymanager

On Android 8.1.0 and above, I am coming up against a major issue.
When connecting to a network with no internet using `enableNetwork`, Android decides after a few seconds to put the device back on the previous network.

I have intentionally connected to the network desired and am planning to use `bindToNetwork` to ensure that all traffic goes through the network, however Android appears to be ignoring the bind and simply disconnecting very quickly afterwards.

I have seen a few permutations of this question being asked here, all with no replies, unfortunately.

I am creating an connecting to the network with the following code. I am able to see the network connecting.

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = desiredSSID;
if (desiredNetwork.has("password")) {
    conf.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", desiredNetwork.get("password"));
}
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);

int networkID = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkID, true);
```

Is there an available option to disable this behaviour, as I intentionally connecting to a network with no internet available.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by removing the existing config from the configured wifi list. The network will not disconnect from a new config.

```
List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigurationList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

for (WifiConfiguration removeConfig : wifiConfigurationList) {
    if (removeConfig.SSID.equals(desiredSSID)) {
        wifiManager.removeNetwork(removeConfig.networkId);
        break;
    }
}
```

Simply adding the network again, as above fixes the issue.

Comment: Doesn't this remove the user's "saved" network so they would have to re-enter the network info to reconnect? Seems like a dangerous/unkind thing to do to the user.

Comment: In my case, this was acceptable as the Wi-Fi was only broadcast for set-up and was not a user's own network, rather an IoT device. Additionally, the app can only remove configurations that it adds.